# Getting a table row with getChildAt gets NullPointerException

Tags: android

I have different tables according to the level the user is in, my code should set the rows of every active table to Visible. So if the user is in level 5, all rows are set as visible until we reach the tablelevel5. The problem is that when I get the row whit getChildAt I get a NullPointerException. Why is that?

```
        for (int i = 0; i<=sharedPreferences.getInt("tableCurrentNumber",1); i++){

        for (int n = 1; i <= verticalLayout.getChildCount(); n++){
            String tableID = "tableLevel" + Integer.toString(n);
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(tableID, "id", getPackageName());
            tableFor = ((TableLayout) findViewById(resID));

            for (int z = 1; z<=tableFor.getChildCount(); z++){

                tableFor.getChildAt(z).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    }
```

logcat:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.root.exercicis/com.example.root.exercicis.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.TableLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.TableLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.root.exercicis.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:200)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 1):

your for loop starts with 1 , it should start with 0

```
for (int z = 0; z < tableFor.getChildCount(); z++){
    tableFor.getChildAt(z).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

for (int n = 0; i < verticalLayout.getChildCount(); n++){
}
```

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: Now the error happens at                 for (int z = 0; z<tableFor.getChildCount(); z++){

Comment: make sure your `findViewById()` working properly and it is not returning null

Comment: it does return null

Comment: then the resource u r going to use is not found there, make sure your id of the `TableLayout`  is correct

Comment: found the issue, the second for had a i instead of a n...thanks